# Issue receiving message from client

Tags: c++, winsock2

I wrote a server app using winsoch2.h to serve as a group chat server using single thread. It is a console application.

I wanted the app to accept multiple clients trying to connect to the server, then when a client sends message to the server, the server receives the message and broadcasts it to other clients connected to the server.

This is the server code I wrote:

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    //Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int initWinsock = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (initWinsock != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cant Innitialize winsock\n";
        return 1;
    }

    //Create a socket
    SOCKET server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Fail to create socket\n";
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Server Socket Created... \nWaiting for connection...\n";

    //Bind Port and IP to socket
    sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    server_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(server, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cerr << "Fail to bind socket\n";
        closesocket(server);
        WSACleanup();
            return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Socket binding successful!!!\nSocket waiting for connections\n";

    //Listening for connections
    listen(server, SOMAXCONN);

    //Create the fd_set and initialize to zero
    fd_set masterConnection;
    FD_ZERO(&masterConnection);
    
    //add server to the fd_set
    FD_SET(server, &masterConnection);

    //create a continous loop
    bool running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        //make a copy of the fd_set
        fd_set copyConnection = masterConnection;

        //check who is talking to the server
        int incoming = select(FD_SETSIZE, &copyConnection, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        //iterate the incoming connection to check the listening socket and messages
        for (int i = 0; i < incoming; i++)
        {
            //the array member of the fd_set holds the socket file descriptor of incoming sockets and message
            SOCKET incomingSocket = copyConnection.fd_array[i];

            //check if it is a listening socket
            if (incomingSocket = server)
            {
                //Accept new connection
                int addr_len = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
                SOCKET client = accept(server, nullptr, nullptr);

                if (client == INVALID_SOCKET)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Failed to accept connection\n";
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "New client accepted\n";

                    //add new connection to list of connection in fd_set
                    FD_SET(client, &masterConnection);

                    //send a welcome message to the new client
                    std::string welcomeMessage = "Welcome to the Awesome Chat Server\nDo have a great time with other clients\n";
                    send(client, welcomeMessage.c_str(), welcomeMessage.length(), 0);
                }
            }
            else //it is a message, read the message and broadcast to all clients
            {
                char receiveBuffer[4096];
                ZeroMemory(receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer));

                //Receive message
                int bytesReceived = recv(incomingSocket, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0);
                std::cout << "Message Received from a client. Broadcasting it now.\n";
                if (bytesReceived <= 0)
                {
                    //Drop Client
                    closesocket(incomingSocket);
                    FD_CLR(incomingSocket, &masterConnection);
                    std::cout << "Client dropped\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Sending out message one: " << receiveBuffer << std::endl;
                    //Send message to other clients
                    for (int i = 0; i < masterConnection.fd_count; i++)
                    {
                        SOCKET sendSock = masterConnection.fd_array[i];
                        if (sendSock != server && sendSock != incomingSocket)
                        {
                            std::string sendBuffer = receiveBuffer;
                            send(sendSock, sendBuffer.c_str(), sendBuffer.length(), 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //remove the server from fd_set and close it
    FD_CLR(server, &masterConnection);
    closesocket(server);

    //send a closing message to all the clients
    std::string sendBuffer = "Server is shutting down. \nGoodbye and have a nice day!!!";
    
    while (masterConnection.fd_count > 0)
    {
        //get each socket
        SOCKET closeSocket = masterConnection.fd_array[0];
        //send goodbye message
        send(closeSocket, sendBuffer.c_str(), sendBuffer.length(), 0);
        //remover from fd_set
        FD_CLR(closeSocket, &masterConnection);
        closesocket(closeSocket);

    }
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

The server is able to connect with multiple clients, but can't receive message from any of them.

My client code is shown below:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
using namespace std;

void receiveData();

SOCKET clientSocket;

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    
    SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr;

    //Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to Initize Winsock" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Create a Socket
    if ((clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to creak socket" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Prepare the socket in structure
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    //connect to server
    if (connect(clientSocket, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to connect to server" << endl;
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Connected to the server\n";

    //Sending and receiving data
    
    string sendBuffer;
    

    while (true)
    {
        thread receiveData1(receiveData);
        

        //send data to server
        cout << "Enter a message: ";
        getline(cin, sendBuffer);
        //cin.getline(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer));

        if (send(clientSocket, sendBuffer.c_str(), sendBuffer.length(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Failed to send Data" << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << "Data sent to server.\n";

        receiveData1.join();

        
    }

    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

void receiveData()
{
    //Receive Data
        //memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    char buffer[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    bytesRead = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytesRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to receive data\n";

    }
    else if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        cerr << "Server Disconnected\n";
        
    }
    else
        cout << "Received: " << buffer << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is most likely because you have no guarantees, whatsoever that `send()` will actually send all the bytes you asked it to send, or that `recv()` will return the exact number of bytes that were sent. See your textbook on network programming for more information on how to correctly send and receive bytes with stream sockets. The shown code fails to implement proper logic for sending and receiving bytes from stream sockets.

Comment: `if (incommingSocket = server)` maybe just this typo

Comment: `std::string sendBuffer = receiveBuffer` and such is a crash waiting to happen. `receiveBuffer` is a buffer, an array of bytes, not a null-terminated C-style string. **Always** store the number of bytes `recv` returns, you **will** need it later.

Comment: Federico nailed it.  It's a typo.